# TIdAttachment - Getting the correct filename of Attachment - without the utf-8 encoding information

Tags: delphi, utf-8, email-attachments, indy, mime

In my project, I try to extract attachments from .eml files.

Under normal conditions (charset ISO), it works. But under special circumstances, it gave me the wrong filename for the Attachment.

Here is what the MessagePart in my example looks like:

```
------=_Part_315_1401515384.1585891801067
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; 
    name="=?UTF-8?Q?Report=5F2020-3=5FCustomerA with some spaces in between.csv?="
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; 
    filename="=?UTF-8?Q?Report=5F2020-3=5FCustomerA with some spaces in between.csv?="

UGFydG5lcjtNYW5kYW50ZW5uYW1lO05hbWU7RmlybWE7U3RyYd9lO1Bvc3RsZWl0emFobDtPcnQ7
TGFuZDtQcm9kdWt0bGluaWU7S3VuZGVuc3RhdHVzO0RhdHVtIFJlZ2lzdHJpZXJ1bmc7QmVnaW5u
IEthdWY7S/xuZGlndW5nIGf8bHRpZyBhYjtBbnphaGwgQmVudXR6ZXI7QW56YWhsIE1vYmlsZSBz
eW5jO05ldHRvIFJlY2hudW5nc2JldHJhZyBpbiBFdXJvO1Byb3Zpc2lvbnNzdHVmZTtQcm92aXNp
b25zYW50ZWlsIGluIEV1cm8NCg==
------=_Part_315_1401515384.1585891801067--
```

Nothing spectacular so far. But for some reason, I don't get the correct filename from that attachment.

Here is my code for getting the filename of that file and save it to a temporary location:

```
function foo(MyMail: TIdMessage; SavePathWithoutBackSlash : string): boolean;
var
 i : Integer;
 lfilename: string;
begin
  for i := 0 to Pred(MyMail.MessageParts.Count) do
    begin
      if (MyMail.MessageParts.Items[i] is TIdAttachmentFile) then
      begin
        lFilename := TIdAttachmentFile(MyMail.MessageParts.Items[i]).FileName;
        TIdAttachmentFile(MyMail.MessageParts.Items[i]).SaveToFile(SavePathWithoutBackSlash + '\' + lFilename);
      end;
    end;
  end; 
end;
```

I have tried a lot with the encodings, but nothing seems to have an impact.

What I expect is a String like: `path/Report_2020-3_CustomerA.csv`

What I get is: `path/=?UTF-8?Q?Report=5F2020-3=5FCustomerA.csv?=`

How can I save the attachment the correct way?

Comment: The comprehensive answer is complex and the solution requires that you recursively traverse the entire email hierarchy, examining the `MyMail.ContentType` at each node, to determine if you're on a "node" or at an attachment. P.S. Your sample code uses [ii], but your loop uses i.

Comment: Did you try [DecodeHeader()](http://ww2.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=DecodeHeader@string.html)?

Comment: @nolanspeaker - What du you mean with that? Every Messagepart is checked if it is TIdAttachmentFile. and if is it will be saved by the Namen, I dont get what you mean. btw. I correct the ii, thanks for Info.

Comment: @Olivier - How should I use DecodeHeader? I tried by doing DecodeHeader(TidAttachmentFile.FileName) but the result ist the same.

Comment: @olivier - I testet a String with Base64 that works (=?UTF-8?B?) in that case DecodeHeader does everything right, but in my example it is quoted/printable (=?UTF-8?Q?) any suggestions on that?

Comment: Okay, I found a Information on a german developerpage (https://www.delphipraxis.net/969765-post26.html) there seams to be a person directly from Indy development involved. The Post discribes exactly what is my Problem. This String is not RFC conform, so blanks are not allows and will not be implemented.

Comment: But I don't see anything wrong in your case. It seems valid.

Comment: @Olivier Indy will have already called `DecodeHeader()` while parsing the data, so calling it again manually won't solve anything if the original data is malformed to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Tanks to @olivier I found a Solution to that Problem. It is a combination of 2 Problems.

First problem:

```
TIdAttachmentFile(MyMail.MessageParts.Items[i]).FileName
```

does not Return `=?UTF-8?Q?` it returns `=_UTF-8_Q_`
So I Changed it to

```
TIdAttachmentFile(MyMail.MessageParts.Items[i]).Name
```

-

Second problem:

According to RFC2047 blank-space are not allowed between `=?...?=`. So DecodeHeader will leave string untouched. My code now works and looks like this:

```
Uses 
  ...IdAttachmentFile, IdMessage, IdCoderHeader...  

function foo(MyMail: TIdMessage; SavePathWithoutBackSlash : string): boolean;
    var
     i : Integer;
     lfilename: string;
    begin
      for i := 0 to Pred(MyMail.MessageParts.Count) do
        begin
          if (MyMail.MessageParts.Items[i] is TIdAttachmentFile) then
          begin
            lFilename := TIdAttachmentFile(MyMail.MessageParts.Items[i]).Name;
            if pos('=?UTF-8?Q?',uppercase(lfilename)) > 0 then
            begin
              lfilename:=StringReplace(lFilename,' ','=20',[rfReplaceAll,rfIgnoreCase]);
            end;
            lFileName:= DecodeHeader(lFileName);
            TIdAttachmentFile(MyMail.MessageParts.Items[i]).SaveToFile(SavePathWithoutBackSlash + '\' + lFilename);
          end;
        end;
      end; 
    end;
```

=20 is the right notation for blanks in UTF-8 with quoted-printable

Comment: A space is a valid UTF-8 string. It's just that RFC 2047 forbids literal spaces in `=?...?=` constructs.

Comment: There are no unencoded spaces in the data you showed in your question. And Indy does not convert `=?UTF-8?Q?` to `=_UTF-8_Q_` like you claim. And you absolutely should be using the `FileName` instead of the `Name`. So I don't see how either of these solutions would make any difference.

Comment: @Remy, yes you are right in my example there was no unencoded spaces, I changed the Data to prevent Informations from going live on thte Internet. Because I was not aware of that Problem I Just leave the blanks out. 
The FileName and Name is exectly like I write it. If I use Filename function Indy will give me no questionmarks at all. Every questionmark is replaced by an _

Comment: @fisi-pjm what you describe is simply not how Indy works. If Indy can't decode the `Name` and `FileName` then it leaves the original data as-is. So the *only* way you could be getting `=_UTF-8_Q_` is if that is what was downloaded to begin with.

Comment: @Remy, thank you for your comment. l will double check that next week. I have a system wich uses a Component to Export mails to eml files. I only checked the original Header Inside that system, not what I get after exporting. It could be possible that the Export tool Changes the data. Thank you for that hint.